# Can't understand this quadratic-trinomial-esque equation

Tags: quadratics

the question was this
if $x^2 -8x + 7 = (x - a)^2 - b$ then the values of $a$ and $b$ are (Multi choice)

the answer was $a = 4, b = 9$ and I don't understand why

Here was my work process

I expanded so it was

$x^2 - 8x + 7 = x^2 - 2ax + a^2 - b
\Rightarrow -8x + 7 = -2ax + a^2 - b$

And I didn't know what to do from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to expand ,

$${\quad ~~ x^2 -8x + 7 = (x - a)^2 - b\\
\Rightarrow (x^2-2\cdot x \cdot 4 + 4^2-16)+7=(x - a)^2 - b\\
\Rightarrow (x-4)^2-9=(x - a)^2 - b \quad \cdots (1)}$$

$(1)$ is an Identity. Comparing both side,

$$\bbox[10px, border: 2px solid black]{a=4,b=9}$$

You can also compare from expanded form,

$$-8x + 7 = 2ax + a^2 - b \quad \cdots (2)$$

$(2)$ is an Identity. Comparing both side,
$$-8=2a\Rightarrow a=4\\ a^2-b=7\Rightarrow 4^2-b=7\Rightarrow b=9\\\bbox[10px, border: 2px solid black]{\therefore a=4,b=9}$$